# sending data between actions within same controller using redirect_to method in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @song = Song.new
  end

  def create
    ids_collection = Array.new
    # some logic to save multiple songs object and accumulate their ids 
    # in ids_collection variable.
    redirect_to new_song_url, notice: "songs saved"
  end

end
```

> > I want followings points to be cleared or answered, hoping these are sensible.
> >     1. I want to pass ids_collection array to 'new' method.
> >     2. when I pass like this (i.e. redirect_to new_song_url(ids_collection)) I get, in url like this (i.e. GET "/songs/new.72%2F73") which is hard to decode in new method.
> >     3. I simply want, 'ids_collection' key in params hash and values as array in that key. How can I achieve that and do I need to whitelist 'ids_collection' for strong parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass key, value pair to `new_song_url`

```
redirect_to new_song_url(song_ids: ids_collection), notice: "songs saved"
```

Then you can access song_ids in `new` action as follows,

```
params[:song_ids]
```

Strong parameters deal with mass assignment, not related to what you are trying to do.

Also note that when you access song_ids in new action, they will be of type string. You may want to convert them into integers, `params[:song_ids].map(&:to_i)`

Comment: Thanks alot !!! Nitish, it's so simple, I couldn't figure it out, means I'm still immature in rails, he he he... thanks alot again.